# How to convert depreciated withRouter to V6 React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to convert this piece of code to v6, but have no idea how to go about it. I've checked the docs and still have no clue how to implement it.

I'm quite new to react and still haven't got the hang of hooks, I know I have to use hooks such as `useNavigate()`, `useParams()` etc. What am I doing wrong?

V5

```js
const CreateBoard = ({ history }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addBoard({ title }, history));
  };


export default withRouter(CreateBoard);
```

V6

```js
const CreateBoard = ({}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate =  useNavigate();
  
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addBoard({ title }));
  };
```

I got rid of `history` and added `useNavigate` but have no idea what to do with it after.

Comment: Oh, I see where the issue/question is now. What where you doing previously with the `history` object in the RRDv5 version of the code? Can you [edit] to include the `addBoard` action code?

Comment: Still need help on this one, and if so can you clarify what the previous `history` usage was in the `addBoard` action?

Comment: No clue unfortunately, trying to refactor this v6 so I'm not well versed with these hooks.

Comment: I was just asking for the "v5" `addBoard` action creator code to be added to the [mcve] so we could see what it does to make a suggestion on a "v6" version of it. If `addBoard` doesn't need it for anything then the code you have is good.